# How to express [Adjective + enough] or [Adverb + enough]

Tags: translation

I've looked online for this but I haven't really found what I'm looking for.

It may be that there is no one formula to express "X enough", but I also wouldn't be surprised if there is.

adjectives:

- They weren't good enough to win.
- He wasn't fast enough to escape.
- I was strong enough to open the bottle.

adverbs:

- She sang well enough to be hired.
- We couldn't solve the problem quickly enough.
- He talked loudly enough to be heard in the next room.

Comment: It seems to make no difference in either E or C whether "enough" qualifies （predicative） adjectives or adverbs.  Was OP unable to find suitable translation among 100 examples at jukuu?

Answer (score 2):

**The basic structures:**

[adjective + **enough**] = [**夠** + adjective]

[adverb + **enough**] =  [**夠**+ adverb]

adjectives:

- Good **enough** = **夠**好; **Not** good **enough** = **不夠**好
- Fast **enough** = **夠**快; **Not** fast **enough** = **不夠**快
- Strong **enough** = **夠**力; **No**t strong **enough** = **不夠**力

adverb:

- Well **enough** = **夠**好; **Not** well **enough** = **不夠**好
- Quickly **enough** =**夠**快; **Not** Quickly **enough** = **不夠**快
- Loudly **enough** = **夠**大聲; **Not** loudly **enough** = **不夠**大聲

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**When the sentence included a verb:**

- She sang well enough. = 她唱得**夠**好
- Couldn't solve quickly enough. = 解得**不夠**快
- He talked loudly enough. = 他說得**夠**大聲

*compare to the basic structure, in a sentence that included a verb, a potential particle like 得  have to be placed after the verb to connect to the adjective or adverb. (得 - to the degree of)

*If the sentences included passive verb like  "**sang**...to  **be hired** /  **talked**...**to be heard** in the next room " , the structure would become more complicated, different type of particles could be used. That would be too broad to answer

Answer (score 0):

够好 or 足够 could be used.

他们做得不够好，赢不了。